# how can i get a copy and make an other application

Tags: c#, duplicates, windows-phone, windows-store

I have a template project and I want to get a copy of that and start a new application with it.
When I try to simple copy paste and run it, it override my template application.

Is there any way to keep original one and use copy like an other project?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what is the IDE - did you copy-paste it in VS solution explorer, or in the disc?

Comment: i am using vs2012 and copy paste on disc. I believe that every solution has a key and windows separete applications with it. If i can change it, application will behave like a different application. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you just [create your own project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) which you use when needed

Comment: it's allow me only make template of a project but i how many project in my solution. I want to make solution's template.